# Perfectly snaping and aligning two objects by face center using the least possible steps?

Tags: modeling, snapping

I want to be able to perfectly center and align one piece of geometry to another that is at an arbitrary angle. The following screenshots demonstrate better what I'm trying to do:

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how to accomplish this simple task in the most efficient way (least possible steps)? I am open to add-ons that offer this functionality via script as well.

Comment: Hello :). Just to save time, what is *your* fastest solution?

Comment: The best I can do is 

1. Place the origin at the bottom center of the cylinder 
2. Select the target face and shift-s > cursor to selected 
3. Select the cylinder > shift-s > selection to cursor
4. Double tap R to rotate and eyeball the correct rotation
5. Examine from different views and tweak the placement

Obviously not optimal :)

Comment: I really think there is an opportunity for an add-on here. Being able to snap to face center when holding CTRL would be awesome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way (to get the ball rolling) :).

1. Poke faces on the target face (to get a center)
2. Enable *Vertex snapping > Median* and *Allow rotation* (to snap origin point)
3. Flip the mesh upside down (since Blender keeps the Z orientation)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sick! Thank you so much for this, that's definitely the most efficient way I've seen so-far. I still think an add-on could make this even more frictionless, but this will definitely do for now.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done faster with some addon :). I'm no expert on this. Perhaps *RobinBetts* or *Lemon* would know.

Comment: Could you please explain the "flip mesh upside down" step in more detail? Like, possibly clarify how you do it, as well as why you do it? I'm trying to follow along, and I'm confused by this step.

Comment: Personally I actually didn't need to flip the mesh upside down at all, it just worked for me on step 2.

Comment: @R-800 That's if you want to snap the top face. Blender tends to snap the bottom one, so one quick fix is to flip the whole mesh.

Answer (score 2):

Put the origin of the object to be placed at the center of the bottom face of that object.
(For instance: Select the bottom face in Edit Mode and do Cursor to Selection. Then in Object mode do Origin to 3D Cursor)

Then put it on the target face you want (anywhere is fine) using Snap to: Face, Snap With: Closest (or Center or Active, not Median), and with the Align Rotation to Target box checked.

Then select you target face and do Cursor to Selection. Select the Object and do Selection to Cursor.

I don't see a faster way without scripting or add-on (for instance Command Recorder or SnapSet).

Comment: Thanks! This does work, but it's very tedious compared to the answer that Jachym Michal gave.

Comment: It seems better, yes. I was a bit slow with posting and didn't see that post : )

Comment: No worries, It's always good to learn multiple ways to attack the same problem :)