# How to place a bone on top of a face with same direction?

Tags: modeling, animation

[image]

How do i place a bone on top of a face like on the picture?

Comment: This might help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184628/perfectly-snaping-and-aligning-two-objects-by-face-center-using-the-least-possib/184638#184638 You only really need Align Rotation To Target while snapping though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable "Copy Attributes menu" addon it comes with blender.

[image: addon]

Offset the bone as needed.
Select the bone and then the plane, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and copy location and rotation

[image: copy menu] [image: results]

Also you can do the snapping on a face with rotation enabled:
[image]
[image]